# Adobe AIR vs. Browser Plugin/Addon

Tags: flash, air, adobe

I would like to convince my client to go for an Adobe AIR and not for a Firefox/Safari/InternetExplorer-Browser-Plugin.

Can you please help me with some arguments and facts? E.g:

- AIR reaches much more people
- Development costs for several browser plugins are much higher
- etc.

Thanks for helping

Comment: You are basically asking for arguments for AIR vs. in-browser Flash? There is not much difference except that AIR allows you a bit more things (like file system access) and does not require you to use a browser.

Comment: First argument is false, flash as a plugin has widest reach. Second is questionable too, Flash *must* run consistently in different browsers.

Comment: It's about AIR vs. Browser-Extension/Plugin. This has nothing todo with Flash as a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Air can access file system in a (normally) secure way.
- Air is a one-for-all solution.
- Air is robust and complies with stable standards. (and seems to continue on that way).

Hope that helps.